# Jupyter Lab, can you stop a cell from showing output in it every time?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-lab

So I have been using Spyder for Python, but I end up writing a lot of comments, and the idea of being able to write text in my code without having to comment it out was intriguing to me, so I started trying Jupyter Lab.

I like the cells and whatnot, but I don't want to have the output of my code shown in a new cell below the cell in which I wrote the code. I added an output view pane on the right-hand side, and that shows my output. That's all I want. I don't want it shown in the left-hand pane under the code cell.

However I can't find any way to stop this from happening. I can collapse the unwanted output cell, but then the next time I run my code, it pops up again.

So in the image below, I do want to see all the "{http.." lines on the right, but NOT on the left under the code block.

Any help would be appreciated!! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Not an answer to hide the output of the cell, but in the attached image the mode is `markdown`, is this the right choice? (That location is to the right of the `reload`)